# Exit onClickListener in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a conditional on a button click and if conditions are met I want to exit the listener.  What is the proper way to exit the method?  Return doesn't seem to work..

```
btnApplyPayment.setOnClickListener {
    if (isFloat(strAmount))            
       //exit here
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
btnApplyPayment.setOnClickListener {
    if (isFloat(strAmount))            
       return@setOnClickListener
 }
```

See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) for reference.